# JDialog within JDialog 

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

How do I add `JDialog` within another `JDialog`?

Comment: I assume that @JB's interpretation is what you really want, just to be sure: you don't mean as a _child_ of the first, do you? (that's not possible, nor reasonable ;) If our assumptions are correct, please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JDialog secondDialog = new JDialog(this); // ("this" is the first JDialog)
secondDialog.setVisible(true)
```

Read the [api doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) and the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).